# Folium HeatMapWithTime html file generated is blank

Tags: python, heatmap, folium

I created a self-contained code to create a HeatMapWithTime map but it shows up as a blank file. This code is run on Jupyter and the output is a 14KB file and I've tried to open it in Chrome, Safari, Firefox but it is still blank.

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from folium.plugins import HeatMapWithTime

# Generate dummy data
latitudes = np.random.uniform(low=45.523, high=45.524, size=50)
longitudes = np.random.uniform(low=-122.675, high=-122.676, size=50)
times = np.sort(np.random.uniform(low=1580000000, high=1600000000, size=50))
data = {'latitude': latitudes, 'longitude': longitudes, 'time': times}

# Create a pandas dataframe from the dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')

# Create a base map
map = folium.Map(location=[45.523, -122.675], zoom_start=13)

# Create a heat map with timeline
HeatMapWithTime(data=df[['latitude', 'longitude', 'time']].values.tolist(),
                           index=df['time'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                           auto_play=True,
                           max_opacity=0.8).add_to(map)

# Save the map to an html file
map.save("heatmap_with_timeline.html")
```

Folium version: 0.14.0
Python version: 3.9.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, the target data for the heatmap is time-series data in date format. The sample data itself was raw data, but it was converted to date format. Also, I think the index of the time animation of the heatmap also needs to be in list format. Finally, the sample data is a latitude/longitude and heatmap value for one time series. Since this folium heatmap is a densitiy heatmap, multiple groups of data may be necessary. To create the data to draw the heatmap, utilizing your sample data, I have added an array of 50 latitude/longitude and heatmap values for each time series index in a loop process for 50 indexes.
For data structures and examples, please refer to the following references. [HeatMapWithTime Plugin](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/HeatMapWithTime.ipynb)

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from folium.plugins import HeatMapWithTime

# Generate dummy data
times = np.sort(np.random.uniform(low=1580000000, high=1600000000, size=50))

data = []
for i in range(len(times)):
    latitudes = np.random.uniform(low=45.423, high=45.524, size=50)
    longitudes = np.random.uniform(low=-122.575, high=-122.676, size=50)
    value = np.random.uniform(0.0, 20.0, 50)
    row = []
    for lat, lon ,v in zip(latitudes,longitudes,value):
        row.append([lat, lon, v])
    data.append(row)

index_time = pd.to_datetime(times, unit='s')
index_time = index_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").tolist()

# Create a base map
m = folium.Map(location=[45.523, -122.675], tiles="stamentoner", zoom_start=11)

# Create a heat map with timeline
hm = HeatMapWithTime(data,
                           index=index_time,
                           auto_play=True,
                           max_opacity=0.8)
hm.add_to(m)
# Save the map to an html file
#map.save("heatmap_with_timeline.html")
m
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
import pandas as pd 
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

#for_map = pd.read_csv('campaign_contributions_for_map.tsv', sep='\t')
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\your_path\\business.csv')
df.head(3)

max_amount = float(df['stars'].max())

hmap = folium.Map(location=[42.5, -75.5], zoom_start=7, )

hm_wide = HeatMap( list(zip(df.latitude.values, df.longitude.values, df.stars.values)),
                   min_opacity=0.2,
                   max_val=max_amount,
                   radius=17, blur=15, 
                   max_zoom=1, 
                 )

hmap.add_child(hm_wide)
```

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import gmplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import folium
from folium import plugins
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\your_path\\lat_lon.csv')

m = folium.Map([40.7379601, -73.9666422], zoom_start=11)
m

X = df[['longitude', 'latitude', 'LOT']].copy()
# mark each station as a point
for index, row in X.iterrows():
    folium.CircleMarker([row['latitude'], row['longitude']],
                        radius=15,
                        popup=row['LOT'],
                        fill_color="#3db7e4", # divvy color
                       ).add_to(m)

# convert to (n, 2) nd-array format for heatmap
stationArr = df[['latitude', 'longitude']].to_numpy()

# plot heatmap
m.add_child(plugins.HeatMap(stationArr, radius=15))
m
```

[image]

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Plotting%20Longitude%20and%20Latitude%20Coordinates%20using%20Folium%20CircleMarker.ipynb

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Plotting%20Longitude%20and%20Latitude%20to%20Visualize%20Spatial%20Data%20for%20NYC%20Taxis.ipynb